# Bus error when setting array element in struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, bus-error

I have the following struct:

```
struct State {
    int num_walls;
    Wall walls[];

    int num_persons;
    Person persons[];
};
```

I want to have persons contain two Persons and walls contain one Wall:

```
int num_walls = 1;
int num_preson = 2;

State simState = *(State*)malloc( sizeof(simState) + num_person*sizeof(Person) + num_walls*sizeof(Wall));
simState.num_walls = num_walls;
simState.num_persons = num_person;
simState.walls[0] = w;
simState.persons[0] = p1;
simState.persons[1] = p2;
```

When I do that I get Bus error (core dumped). When I only set the persons, everything works fine. I.e. this works:

```
int num_walls = 0;
int num_preson = 2;

State simState = *(State*)malloc( sizeof(simState) + num_person*sizeof(Person) + num_walls*sizeof(Wall));
simState.num_walls = num_walls;
simState.num_persons = num_person;
// simState.walls[0] = w;
simState.persons[0] = p1;
simState.persons[1] = p2;
```

The code is c++11 and I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

Why does that happen?

Comment: Your `struct State` definition is incorrect it cannot compile. Please provide your _actual_ code.

Comment: This is not legal C++ `Wall walls[];`

Comment: @john Not legal C either, since not at the end of the `struct`. OP: Please tag only the language that you intend this to be. C *or* C++. At the moment the code should not compile in either of the two languages.

Comment: This is my actual code. If I change it to Wall* walls; I get an assertion error for malloc: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb)' failed.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a variable length structure, with a single allocation. If that is so, then this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: If this is your actual code, your compiler is broken. As mentioned before `Wall walls[];` is not legal.

Comment: Oh and `*(State*)malloc( ...` doesn't make any sens. What is your platform/IDE/compiler/OS/...?

Comment: @FerdiK Please form a complete [repro] and tell us which compiler you are using that is compiling it, because as it is it should not compile.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You struct definition cannot compile. You're not showing the code you compile.

Comment: My struct def is in a header file. It's copy pasted and what I compile. I then instantiate a State as shown in the code in the question and pass it on to a function that does a computation on it.

Comment: @FerdiK please don't _describe_ your code, show a [mcve]. This may require some work. Also condider the  answer below. Ans maybe you should also tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: Just to clarify, the GCC version that you are using does indeed compile the code. But arrays with unknown bounds are not allowed in C++ as `struct` members and in C they are only allowed at the end of the struct (so-called "flexible array member"). That GCC allows it somewhere else in the struct seems to be a bug, which seems to be fixed since GCC 6. Use the `-pedantic-errors` flag to force GCC to issue error messages for such constructs that are not actually allowed in C++ and are just a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: Also, if you really intend to write C++, not C, then you have picked up some wrong idioms. You should not use `malloc` like this in C++. I suggest you learn the language with a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @FerdiK If you used `std::vector<Wall>` and `std::vector<Person>` instead of the fake C++ syntax in that `struct`, not only will you have legal C++ code, you would not need to have those other members that hold the number, since a vector knows how many elements it has by just calling `vector::size()`, plus the code is easier to maintain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I will clarify things shortly. The problem is that we are supposed to write code in C but a colluege started writing in Cpp. That's messy from my part, I'll clear things up and come back.

Comment: Okay, the problem actually was what @john pointed out: "do not have to allocate simState, it gets it's memory just by being declared, but you do have to allocate your two variable length arrays". Thanks a lot for the help and also thanks for the other tips about Cpp and C. My confusion about using C vs.Cpp idioms came from that we have an algorithm in C that needs to be optimized as much as possible and we write the rest in Cpp. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is legal C++, it may be what you are trying to achieve

```
struct State {
    int num_walls;
    Wall* walls;
    int num_persons;
    Person* persons;
};

State simState;
simState.num_walls = num_walls;
simState.walls = new Wall[num_walls];
simState.num_persons = num_person;
simState.persons = new Person[num_person];
simState.walls[0] = w;
simState.persons[0] = p1;
simState.persons[1] = p2;
```

It's not good C++, but at least it's legal.

The important points (in either language) is that you do not have to allocate `simState`, it gets it's memory just by being declared, but you do have to allocate your two variable length arrays `simState.persons` and `simState.walls`

Comment: Gives me a seg fault.

Comment: @FerdiK Well you have a bug somewhere else, without seeing more code it's impossible to say where.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to define dimensionless arrays in C++, you should be using pointer with allocation (new or even malloc) as stated by others.

Dimensionless arrays are valid construct in C99, it's not called VLA but [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). This feature of language can be used only as last member of structure with several other restrictions on definition and usage. Definitely not regularly used feature.

Reason for "Bus error" on first example is illegal definition of **wall** it's not last member of struct. Since **person** is correctly defined you are accessing memory past structure and overwriting something else which is really not what you want to do. GCC is reason why your program compiles even when it's not valid since lot of extensions is enabled by default. Please use **-pedantic** flag together with version of C++ standard (-std=c++11) to get warning about that.